# Why isn't Baki of the Sand fighting in the Fourth Great Shinobi War?

Tags: naruto

The last time I've seen him was after the Five Kage Summit Arc. Since then, we haven't seen him. Despite him being a Jonin-level Shinobi, I can't remember him being on the battlefield, so my question is: why is it that this character (along with other Shinobi) isn't included by Kishi in this part of the anime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another Jonin level shinobi that is missing from the 4th Great Shinobi War is Kurenai (this maybe because of her pregnancy), Ebisu and Ibiki Morino too are missing and he too is of Jounin level.

Since nothing specifically has been stated about their absence we can only deduce that either

1> These shinobi have been dispatched on some special mission and that is not shown in the manga, or

2> These shinobi have been given the duty to protect the civilians that are not directly taking part in the war.

My two cent would be on the speculation that they are protecting the civilians that are not directly taking part in the war. These civilians need to be protected, and the generals need to dispatch a small group of quality fighters that would be able to defend them or move them to safety.

Answer (score -1):

In the episode where the leaf village is attacked ebisu is shown to be in charge of defending the village.

But I don't know where the rest are sadly.